# Scatter matrix Sw Sb and St in python

Tags: python, matrix, scatter

I'm trying to compute the Sw, Sb and St scatter Matrix in python language,

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I know that there are library with implementations of scatter matrix for plotting like the following

```
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
```

I want to know if exists any library in python that compute those scatter matrix without plot. I would appreciate any example.